# Why does the text look strange (thick/bold, closer) in Inkscape?

Tags: svg, text, fonts, inkscape, typeface

I am using Inkscape 1.2 (dc2aedaf03, 2022-05-15).

No matter which font I use the text looks ugly. The letters are very close and touch each other. Text, in general, is very thick/bold even in normal variety. If I apply bold, they get further thicker. I tried to lookup for any relevant settings in the preferences but didn't find anything.

Here is an example of how it looks:
[Examples of different fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfMuc.png)

Comment: I suspect you may have both the fill and the stroke for the text. If this is not helping you please edit your question and add the code for the text

Comment: Oh well! I didn't think this was possible! That was the case indeed, the text now looks normal after I deselected stroke paint option. If you can add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Btw, what do you mean by post the code? Is there any code on the Inkscape backend that's possible to be seen?

Comment: Please ask inkskape questions here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/?tags=inkscape.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Didn't know of this dedicated forum.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because belongs to graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Comment: One perhaps helpful example which doesn't provide a default but style can be copied via `ctrl`+`shift`+`v`: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/156355/how-can-you-make-bold-text-if-the-font-does-not-have-bold-included

Answer (score 6):

@[enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta)'s comment is correct: by opening the [Fill and Stroke](https://inkscape-manuals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fill-and-stroke-dialog.html) inspector tab, selecting the **Stroke paint** tab within it, and clicking the `x` icon for `No Paint`, I was able to resolve a similar issue.